# Why webpack resolve.alias use @ success, use ~ is error?

Tags: javascript, webpack

in my `webpack.config.js`, the following code works:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  },
  aliasFields: ['wepy'],
  modules: ['node_modules']
},

// in .js file is work
import Api from '@/model/api'
```

But when I modify it to ~ compile it cannot find the corresponding module.

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~': path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  },
  aliasFields: ['wepy'],
  modules: ['node_modules']
},

// in .js file is not work
import Api from '~/model/api'
```

tip `ReferenceError: Api is not defined`

Comment: Because you define alias `@`

Comment: @TanDuong he clearly said that he modified his alias to `~`

Comment: @RuChernChong: Sorry, I misunderstand the question. `~` use for import from `node_module`.